# Is it possible to concat a query from 2 tables whose objects inherit from the same base class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have 2 objects in an Entity Framework code first app that inherit from the same base class. This gives me 2 tables in the db.  Is it possible to query both tables in one db transaction?

Right now, I make 2 queries and merge the results.  This seems terribly inefficient if I could just pass the result.

```cs
///In and Out inherit from a class called Transaction
IQueryable<In> insBaseQuery = _context.Ins;
IQueryable<Out> outsBaseQuery = _context.Outs;

if (filteringOn)
{
   insBaseQuery = insBaseQuery.Where(x => x.LocationId == myLocation); 
   outsBaseQuery = outsBaseQuery.Where(x => x.LocationId == myLocation);
}

var ins= insBaseQuery.Include(x => x.Details);
var outs = outsBaseQuery.Include(x => x.Details).Include(x => x.EvenMoreDetails);

var result = new List<Transaction>();
result.AddRange(await ins.ToListAsync(cancellationToke));
result.AddRange(await outs.ToListAsync(cancellationToken));
return result.AsEnumerable();
```

The only difference between the objects is one additional field that needs to be passed in the result (EvenMoreDetails).  With the above method, I don't have access to this field.

Comment: Why do you have 2 tables if you want to handle all together? The ForeignKey `EvenMoreDetails` should be nullable. If both tables are different you have to query both anyway. In best case you create two queries and concat them with a union. This can also be done in your code and this way you got your objects in correct classes.

Comment: Based on which table the data is in, I know which direction the transaction occurred (business logic).  For example, a box can come into a building and out a building.  The EvenMoreDetails field only applies in the out direction, but could also be null in the out direction if the data wasn't collected.

Comment: This method is going to be part of a new API that merges the in and out transactions for display in a new table view (not for a machine).  Internally, everything uses distinct APIs for ins and outs.  Something I've debated is making the result of this query create an entirely new object type that also notes the type of transaction.

Comment: Why not using one transaction-table which has a column `step` which contains `in` or `out`? You could use a `View` to 'fake' a table which contains both. But anyway you have to choose: One type in one table with optional properties *or* two types in two tables + some logic to concat them.

Comment: Making it one table seems completely logical and will probably be what I end up doing.  However, it's going to take a lot of rework and migrations for existing methods.